# Using Jquery ajax to call ActionResult method in Controller and return data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to understand how the Jquery Ajax methods works. Right now, I have some problems calling the ActionResult method in the controller that will return a PartialView.

Have created an button which I will use to get new data in from the server (Ajax call should run)

**Code: (ActionResult in Home controller)**

```
public ActionResult All()
    {
        List<Student> model = db.Students.ToList();

        return PartialView("_Student", model);
    }
```

This method is the one I'm trying to call when I press the button in the main Index view.

**Code: (Index view)**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="small-12 column sbw-travel">
    <h2>Travel</h2>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <button id="button1" class="sbw-travel-button">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="small-12 sbw-travel-box" id="rooms">

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

When the user hit the button, an Ajax call should run, and the list will appear in the section with id=rooms.

**Script: (Ajax code)**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button1').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: @Url.Action("All", "Home"),
            datatype: "html",
            success: function () { 
                $('#rooms').html(???);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Can any of you see if I have forgot something to make this run like I have described?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result is on the succes event. Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#button1').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: @Url.Action("All", "Home"),
        datatype: "html",
        success: function (data) { 
            $('#rooms').html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
}); });
```

Comment: So far nothing happens.. if i debug, I'm getting an error: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'All', but not sure what it means yet.

Comment: You are invalid character on your response data. You should escape strings and put them to quotes

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest loading firebug when you click the button (enable the console), make sure the requested URI is responding with valid HTML data on the click event.

I also generally find using something like:

```
$('#button1').on('click', function () { ...
```

usually yields better results, see here: [Difference between .on('click') vs .click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click)