# Action Result within a div from ajax call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I need a view to be shown within a div in my DOM..This view is triggered only if a button is pressed. I'm failing to achieve this and I do not understand why. I searched for some other topics and used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33201617/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-actionresult-method-in-controller-and-return-data) as my reference to build my own .

**DIV**

```
<div id="ViewDetalhes" class="col-md-10 modal-content" style="margin-left: 2%;">
<a href="#" data-window="#ViewDetalhes-Close" class="bt-fechar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
<h4 class="titulo">Histórico do usuário</h4>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div style="margin: 0;padding: 1% 0;width: 100%;text-align:center;">
        <span class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x text-primary" style="color:red;"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<h4 class="titulo">&nbsp;</h4>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right" data-window="#ViewDetalhes-Close"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Fechar</button>
```

**Button**

```
<td class="text-center"><a id="Historico" href="/Relatorios/GetHistoricoUsuarios/?UsID=@item.UsuarioID" data-window="#ViewDetalhes-Open"  class="bt-acao" title='Histórico'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a></td>
```

**Jquery and Ajax**

```
$("#Historico,#ViewDetalhes > a.bt-fechar, #ViewDetalhes > button").on(
    "click",
    function () {
        var modo = $(this).data('window').split("-")[1];
        var window = $(this).data('window').split("-")[0];
        function onManutencaoAcao() {};
        $('.w3-modal').css("zIndex", 3);
        Window.Modal(modo, window, onManutencaoAcao);
        return false;           
    }    
);


$("#ViewDetalhes > div").on("click",
    function ExibirHistorico() {
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            //url: @Url.Action("GetHistoricoUsuarios", "Relatorios"),
            url: '/Relatorios/GetHistoricoUsuarios',
            dataType: 'html',               
            success: function (data) {
                $('#ViewDetalhes').html(data);
               //$('#ViewDetalhes > div').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

**Action Result**

```
public ActionResult GetHistoricoUsuarios(int? pagina = 1, string PDF = "N", int EmID = 0, int FiID = 0, int UsID = 0, string Usuario = "", string Telefone = "", string Procedencia = "", string Exclusor = "")
    {

        string Area = Session["Area"].ToString();
        int UserID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]);
        int EmpresaID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["EmpresaID"]);
        int FilialID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["FilialID"]);
        int ConsultorID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ConsultorID"]);
        int referenciaID = PageList.GetReferenciaID(Area, FilialID, EmpresaID, ConsultorID, 0);
        referenciaID = (Area == "CRE") ? ConsultorID : referenciaID;
        referenciaID = (Area == "MAS") ? UserID : referenciaID;

        EmID = (EmID == 0) ? EmpresaID : EmID;
        FiID = (FiID == 0) ? FilialID : FiID;

        ViewBag.EmID = EmID;
        ViewBag.FiID = FiID;
        ViewBag.UsID = UsID;
        ViewBag.Usuario = Usuario;
        ViewBag.Telefone = Telefone;
        ViewBag.Procedencia = Procedencia;
        ViewBag.Exclusor = Exclusor;

        //Definindo a paginação              
        int paginaQdteRegistros = (Session["RegistrosPorPagina"] == null) ? 10 : Convert.ToInt32(Session["RegistrosPorPagina"]);
        int paginaNumeroNavegacao = (pagina ?? 1);

        List<ViewModelHistoricoUsuarios> Relatorio = Relatorios.HistoricoUsuarios(EmID, FiID, UsID, Usuario, Procedencia, Exclusor);
        return View(Relatorio.ToPagedList(paginaNumeroNavegacao, 6));

    }
```

I'm getting this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUP3i.png), the view should be loaded there instead of this red spin. I feel this is very simple, yet I can't understand.

Comment: Open your dev tools console tab and see whether you are getting any errors. Also check whether the network call (ajax call) is made and the response is expected (200OK)

Comment: As you suggested, I checked the console and I do not have any errors, whereas in the network call I realized that it is not being called. Do you have any clue why?

Comment: If i pass the URL like this url: @Url.Action("GetHistoricoUsuarios", "Relatorios") it will call the ajax in the network , but it opens the view in a new page.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my ajax to this and it worked.

```
$("#Historico").on("click", function () {
    var URLAjax = this.href;
    alert(URLAjax);
    function onManutencaoAcao() {};
    $('.w3-modal').css("zIndex", 3);
    Window.Modal("Open", "#ViewDetalhes", onManutencaoAcao);

    $.ajax( {
        type: 'GET',
        url: URLAjax,              
        dataType: 'html',
        beforeSend: function () {
            var html = '<div style="margin: 0;padding: 1% 0;width: 100%;text-align:center;">' + 
                '<span class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x text-primary" style="color:red;"></span>' + 
            '</div>';
            $('#ViewDetalhes > div').html(html);
        },
        success: function (html) {
            $('#ViewDetalhes > div').html(html);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```